# JS prompt open in new safari window?

Tags: javascript, safari, applescript

The following script opens a JS prompt with text in a new tab and I would like it to do the same thing, only in a new window. What would I need to change in order to achieve this?

```
    set searchTerm to “ebay”

    do shell script "/usr/bin/osascript -e 'delay 1' -e 'tell application \"System         Events\" to keystroke \"" & searchTerm & space & "\"' > /dev/null 2>&1 &"

    tell application "Safari"
        activate
        set newTab to make new tab in window 1
        set current tab of window 1 to newTab
        do JavaScript         "javascript:Qr=prompt('','');if(Qr)location.href='http://www.yubnub.org/parser/parse?        command='+escape(Qr)" in current tab of first window
    end tell
```

Comment: I tried this and it opens the prompt in a new window but when I press enter, it jumps to the first page and opens it there.                                                               tell application "Safari"
 make new document
end tell
set searchTerm to "ebay"

do shell script "/usr/bin/osascript -e 'delay 1' -e 'tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"" & searchTerm & space & "\"' > /dev/null 2>&1 &"

tell application "Safari"
 activate
 do JavaScript "javascript:Qr=prompt('','');if(Qr)location.href='http://www.yubnub.org/parser/parse?command='+escape(Qr)" in document 1
end tell

Comment: You are calling an AppleScript within a shell script within an Apple Script. Is there any particular reason why? I'd recommend putting the "delay 1" and "tell application 'System Events'"... at the bottom of your existing script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is make a new document

```
set searchTerm to "ebay"

do shell script "/usr/bin/osascript -e 'delay 1' -e 'tell application \"System         Events\" to keystroke \"" & searchTerm & space & "\"' > /dev/null 2>&1 &"

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    set thisWindow to make new document
    tell thisWindow to do JavaScript "javascript:Qr=prompt('','');if(Qr)location.href='http://www.yubnub.org/parser/parse?        command='+escape(Qr)"

end tell
```

Comment: Thank you. The script that you posted is exactly what I was trying to do. It only works when Safari is not in full screen. When it is in full screen, it opens the prompt in a new window and as soon as I press enter, it jumps to the previous window and goes to the page in that one instead of the new window that it created. Since full screen is my preferred method of browsing, Any ideas why full screen mode does this?

Comment: I figured it out. After replacing the last part with "thiswindow", everything works now.         set searchTerm to "ebay"

do shell script "/usr/bin/osascript -e 'delay 1.4' -e 'tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"" & searchTerm & space & "\"' > /dev/null 2>&1 &"

tell application "Safari"
 activate
 set thisWindow to make new document
 do JavaScript "javascript:Qr=prompt('','');if(Qr)location.href='http://www.yubnub.org/parser/parse?command='+escape(Qr)" in thisWindow
end tell

Comment: Awesome, i'm glad you got it worked out what i meant to do was as a tell thisWindow to do Javascript

Answer (score -1):

Nothing an author can do can choose to open in a new window instead of a new tab.

Comment: I'm sorry for wording that wrong but the statement I said works either way you can not decide wether it is a new tab or new window, this is something that is decided by the user in their browser settings.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. The following is the original script that opens in the current tab. Above, it was modified to open in a new tab. I am simply trying to open it the same way, only in a new window.                  set searchTerm to "ebay"

do shell script "/usr/bin/osascript -e 'delay 1' -e 'tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke \"" & searchTerm & space & "\"' > /dev/null 2>&1 &"

tell application "Safari"
 activate
 do JavaScript "javascript:Qr=prompt('','');if(Qr)location.href='http://www.yubnub.org/parser/parse?command='+escape(Qr)" in current tab of first window
end tell